# Responsive right pointing CSS chevrons? Possible?

Tags: css

I need to find a responsive solution to the following code.

HTML:

```
<span>&nbsp;</span><span>&nbsp;</span><span>YES!</span>
```

CSS:

```
span {
 color: #bac12d;
 background-color: #213d55;
 display: inline-block;
 position: relative;
 margin-right: 10px;
 margin-left: 30px;
 font-size: 80px;
 line-height: 1;
}
span:before {
 content: "";
 display: inline-block;
 border-left: 20px solid transparent;
 border-top: 40px solid #213d55;
 border-right: 0px solid #213d55;
 border-bottom: 40px solid #213d55;
 position: absolute;
 z-index: -1;
 top: 0;
 left: -20px;
}
span:after {
 content: "";
 display: inline-block;
 border-left: 20px solid #213d55;
 border-top: 40px solid transparent;
 border-right: 0px solid transparent;
 border-bottom: 40px solid transparent;
 position: absolute;
 z-index: -1;
 top: 0;
 right: -20px;
}
span:nth-child(-n+2){
  width: 0px;
}
```

Here is my fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/283azx0t/

Is it possible to make it responsive so that it follows font-size?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes this is possible with EM units.

Here is a rough fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/zbetxu8g/1/

Here is something like what you want to do for the approach, but choose better em measurements:

```
span:before {
  ...
  border-left: 2em solid transparent;
  border-top: 4em solid #213d55;
  border-right: 0px solid #213d55;
  border-bottom: 4em solid #213d55;
  ...
  left: -2em;
}
```

Comment: This could work if it's possible to get the text inside the span without the extra em tag.

Comment: ems can be any measurement. 0.25em, 10ems etc. You'll have to tweak. I just removed the zero from all your measurements to get the result in the fiddle. The <emphasis> is not necessary if you choose the right em units...

Answer (score 1):

Yes this is possible with media query. As per the different screen size change the font size and also the background arrow size.

Comment: Well yeah, but I'm looking for something where you only have to change the font size per media query. The triangle borders do not follow the font size in my example. The remain the same height when you change font size.

Comment: As per the media query just change the font size and also its alignment.

Comment: Although it works, It's not very practical to change alignment for every media query and font size change.